# Modify For loop to go from certain string forward and delete a selection of lines using batch

Tags: json, windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Ok so i am writing a batch file in which i delete every line containing "," after finding string:
"plugins": {
Is it possible to make this condition in for loop ?

now i know you can avoid quotes using ^ but i just cant make it work.

what i do right now is the following:

```
@echo OFF
::removePlugins
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    echo. 2>tempPackage.json
    SET @FOUND=0
    for /F "delims=" %%G in (./package.json) do (   
        echo %%G|find "," > nul
        if not errorlevel 1 (SET @FOUND=1)  
     
        if !@FOUND!==1(
            @echo ON
            SET @FOUND=0
            ECHO:     >> tempPackage.json
            @echo OFF
        ) 
        ECHO %%G>>tempPackage.json
    )
    move "./tempPackage.json" ".package.json"
```

So in this case i would only make a new line in every line that contains ",".
So how does one write a for loop that only goes from this string forward and not make new line but delete it?.

the expected result after runing the batch would be :

```
{
"scripts"{ still the same scripts},
"dependencies"{ still the same dependencies},
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [],
    "plugins": {}
  }
}
}
```

I tryed to use the code from @Stephan , like this:

```
@echo OFF 
::removePlugins
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET @findPlugins=0
find /i /c "plugins" ./package.json >NUL
if not errorlevel 1 (SET @findPlugins=1)

IF !@findPlugins!==1 (
    SET "@FOUND=1"
    >tempPackage.json (
    for /F "delims=" %%G in (./package.json) do (  
        echo %%G|findstr /b "}" >nul && SET "@FOUND=1"
        if defined @FOUND ECHO %%G
        echo %%G|findstr /b "\"plugins\": {" >nul && SET "@FOUND="
    )
    )
    type tempPackage.json
)
```

And it just rewrote the json to temp and didnt delete anything...what am  i doing wrong ?

Comment: I am positively sure I am not getting what you are asking. Please edit and clarify, showing input as well as expected results.

Comment: @Gerhard Done , I added what you asked for

Comment: Hm - would `find /v "{}," oldfile.json > newfile.json` do what you want?

Comment: Idk where u meant for that to be replaced but if i replace this at the part ```ECHO:     >> tempPackage.json ``` it does not work, also tried it in a few different ways but they are all quite far from where i want it to be

Comment: it was meant to replace your whole batch file. It works with your example data, but I'm not sure if it works with your original data (it might have matching lines that you don't want to remove in different parts of the file)

Comment: Oh it was meant to delete all the {},....yeah no the scripts and dependencies also have this kind of files inside theres just so many that for reading reasons i rather typed that. I now also added 1 more plugin just to show that there can be many more different variants but they all end with "," so that is my goal

Comment: @Stephan, OP's example json is highly flawed. :). Then to Brian Orion. You posted some examples which makes little sense. 1. post a true example 2. Consider Powershell for this  and not batch files. Complicated json's can easily be corrupted by brute forcing a structured layout. One reason being exactly as you saw now. Stephan has a great solution, but it is VERY specific to your posted example. if the example changes, so does the method.

Comment: I am a novice in this and this is the exact example that i need to do..the goal is that anything inside plugins must be deleted so the main issue here is setting the for loop to go from then on and then delete the rows that contain any data... The code i did is just a thing i tried.. and it has to be a batch file since there are a few others being called with it.... I understand what you mean but i cant type more then i did..

Comment: You should use a language that natively the supports JSON format rather than trying to interpret it as normal text! Anyway, your example data is illegal JSON (the first two lines violate the format), so please copy the correct sample data into you post! *N. B.:* `if !@FOUND!==1(` should read `if !@FOUND!==1 (`…

Comment: use powershell instead which has [built-in JSON support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/working-with-json-data-in-powershell/)

Comment: I can't use anything else then batch i understand the example json is flawed so can you then at least tell me if i can modify the for loop to start looping only after plugins ?

Comment: You can use powershell commands from within your `batch-file`, but doing the actual replacement using standard `cmd` commands is a bad idea.

Comment: Your modifications to the sample data made your original title invalid as the line `...ionic-webview...` does not contain a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind, batch can't interpret `.json` files and handles them as pure text. So any batch solution will highly depend on the exact format of the file. Any change in the format (a stray space might be enough) may cause trash.

That said: use a flag that changes at (each) line that starts with `"plugins":` and changes back when hitting the line starting with `}` (end of the block) and write the line dependent on the flag:

```
@echo OFF
::removePlugins
setlocal 

SET "@FLAG=1"
>tempPackage.json (
  for /F "delims=" %%G in (./package.json) do (  
    echo %%G|findstr /e "[^{]}" >nul && SET "@FLAG=1"
    if defined @FLAG ECHO %%G
    echo %%G|findstr "\"plugins\":" >nul && SET "@FLAG="
  )
)
type tempPackage.json
```

Comment: I tryed your code and for some reason it only outputs same data as the package.json contains.....so once again i will post the exact part in which i want the plugins to be deleted.

Comment: Your new example makes it a completely different problem. Probably solvable, but give me some time to think about it. Or use a language that can interpret JSON.

Comment: Easier than I thought. Just a little bit playing with the `findstr` searchstrings. See my edited answer. Remember: any change in formatting in the json-file is possibly devastating.

Comment: Damn i didnt realize that the construct of my question changes the solution completely...Thank you kind sir this solved my problem :D

Comment: Just out of curiosity..how would you write the findstr if the plugins would end with `new line   }` and not `}, new line "im.ltdev.cordova.UserAgent": {}`

Comment: You need to identify the line that ends the `plugins` block. If there is no line identifiable by itself, you need to use a counter (+1 if a new block starts (`{`) , -1 if a block ends (`}`) and reset the flag when the counter reaches zero. Might turn out as a nightmare with pure batch...

Answer (score -1):

This uses a regex to capture everything up to the "plugins" line.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    Get-Content -Raw .\pi.txt ^| ^
    ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match '(?sm)(.*\"plugins\": {).*') { $Matches[1] + \"`n`n}\" ^| Out-File -FilePath '.package.json'}}
```